# Chrome control SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am developing an SharePoint-hosted app.
Can I edit the chrome control for an aspx page?
For html page it is easy but for aspx I don't know how do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aspx page inherited the Master Page app.master. So the chrome control always rendered by default on every aspx page within your solutions.

If you want to remove the  tag and use the aspx page as an normal HTML page, [this article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Use-the-b7744b48) might help.

If not, my solution is develop your custom Master page, take a look at the `<div id="suiteBar" class="ms-fullWidth">` which is the chrome control rendered by default. You can remove/edit default chrome control and develop your custom one as the same way you did in HTML page.